# Autoprefixer in VSCode - TypeError: Cannot read property 'warnings' of null?

Tags: visual-studio-code, null, autoprefixer

I'm trying use "Autoprefixer" in VS Code but instead of using it vs code output
"[Autoprefixer]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'warnings' of null"

I tried reinstall vs Code and extensions but didnt work.

[Autoprefixer]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'warnings' of null

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I used it when the file was a .html file. But if I used a .css file with my CSS formatted correctly, it worked. I didn't get any response and my code was updated with the prefixes.